# Relationship between paper and pencil markings on it

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the relationship between a piece of paper and pencil marks drawn on it. Ideally, the word could be used to describe the same type of relationship between a canvas and paint, photograph paper and ink, and so on. However, the word should not imply *containing* — it should be strictly for things on the outside of these objects. This word should not be used to describe the relationship between a computer and its software or stored data, and the relationship between a VCR tape and its stored data.

*Example Sentence:*

> "All files, documents, or other written, photographic, or other tangible material __________ proprietary information, shall be the property of the Company."

[ __ NOT ‘containing’__ ]

Alternatively, if there is no word that can describe this relationship, I'm looking for a different phrasing that would allow such a description.

The best I can come up with is *hold*. Does the paper *hold* the pencil marks on it? Does a canvas *hold* paint? It still doesn't sound quite right.  *Contain* is a synonym of *hold*, but that doesn't sound right either.

Related: Does the usage of "material" imply that this is only for things that are most similar to paper or canvas, and can be *written on*, as opposed to "storing" information, thereby limited the application of this word to things other than complex technology?

Comment: You call them "markings." How about "marked with"?

Comment: 'Bearing' would work in some arcane registers, but  'with pencil marks / writing / drawings on it' is far more idiomatic. What is the reason you reject the container metaphor? 'This sheet contains vital information.'

Comment: @Tonepoet The OP has an example sentence -- it is the second paragraph.  I'll try to make it more obvious.

Comment: @ab2 Oh, you are right. My apologies to you Ari. It still technically needs to check a thesaurus as a matter of policy though, although I must admit it is a silly requirement in this case because I doubt a synonym of containing would actually be the desired word.

Comment: "involving" is unspecific; "including" is a possibility.

Comment: I agree with Mitch, it seems like you are trying to invent a legally watertight term where it is likely that one already exists, as the desire to retain such property cannot be unique.

Comment: 'Rendered with' or 'displaying'?

Comment: Containing does fit this usage, btw.

Answer (score 1):

[Bearing, as participle of the verb "bear"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bear)
...

> 1.2 Have or display as a visible mark or feature.
>
> ‘many of the papers bore his flamboyant signature’

Answer (score 0):

Consider *show*.

> **show** *verb*
>   1:  to cause or permit to be seen 
>   [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show)

Searching [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=canvas%20*_VERB%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccanvas%20%2A_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcanvas%20is_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20was_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20has_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20representing_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20shows_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20depicting_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20showing_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20covering_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20becomes_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20had_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Ccanvas%20*_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcanvas%20is_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20was_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20has_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20representing_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20shows_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20depicting_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20showing_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20covering_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20becomes_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcanvas%20had_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0) for appropriate verbs to suit '*canvas (verb) a*' yields the following:

[image]

Skipping past *is* and *was*, the most relevant verb is *has*. However, this sounds like your rejected *containing*. *Depicting* and *representing* might be too specific to pictorial imagery, which brings us to *showing*.

Here are a couple of examples:

- Painting, oil on canvas, showing a swampy landscape at sunset, with ...
  [- Warman's Country Antiques by Mark F. Moran](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=R9be4dxq9O4C&pg=PA22&dq=%22canvas%20showing%20a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBqoXDo8HVAhUKnZQKHY3OCokQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22canvas%20showing%20a%22&f=false)
- She took a canvas showing a just-started picture from the easel ...
  [- Five Smooth Stones by Ann Fairbairn](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=6LCyGHyLCU8C&pg=PA400&dq=%22canvas%20showing%20a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBqoXDo8HVAhUKnZQKHY3OCokQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%22canvas%20showing%20a%22&f=false)

Your example would then be:

- All files, documents, or other written, photographic, or other tangible material showing proprietary information shall be the property of the Company.

Answer (score 0):

In CHARM ([www.charminfo.org](http://www.charminfo.org)), an ontology for cultural heritage, we use the terms **embodiment** and **material aspect** to express this. From the specification:

> A **representation** is the description of the persistent manner in which certain contents are captured on an embodiment, reflecting the forms and characteristics of the former.
>
> A **material aspect** is an entity that is inextricably embedded into another material entity, named its support, and which has been added to it after the creation of the latter.

In this manner, the piece of paper is the *embodiment* of what has been written or drawn on it. The pencil marks on the paper are a *material aspect* of the paper.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ***carry*** (which happens to be a synonym of ***bear*** as answered already) helps here.

> "All files, documents, or other written, photographic, or other
>   tangible material ***carrying*** proprietary information, shall be the
>   property of the Company."

ODO:

> **[carry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/carry)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **5.3** Be known or **marked by**.
>   ‘the product does not carry the swallow symbol’
>
> ‘The trains, which all carry the name Thameslink Cityflier, were expected to offer a full service by today.’